# Bash, any compound command as shell function body

Tags: bash, function, shell, for-loop

According to Bash info page shell function definition's syntax is

```
NAME () COMPOUND-COMMAND [ REDIRECTIONS ]
```

or

```
function NAME [()] COMPOUND-COMMAND [ REDIRECTIONS ]
```

> The BODY of the function is the compound command COMPOUND-COMMAND
>   (*note Compound Commands::).  That command is usually a LIST enclosed
>   between { and }, but may be any compound command listed above.

source: Bash info pages.

The `for'-loop command is one of compound command constructs supported by Bash.

Why does the following not want to work then (some kind of interpretor error)?

```
function f_indent for (( i=0 ; i<$1 ; i++ )) ; do echo -n " " ; done
```

Comment: Works for me. Are you sure that you're using bash? What error does it throw?

Comment: For me it fails with a syntax error on bash 3.2, but works on bash 4.4.  To get it to work on 3.2 I have to: `function f_indent { for (( i=0 ; i<$1 ; i++ )) ; do echo -n " " ; done; }`

Comment: Me needs same workaround as cdarke user to get it working. Please give me more time to check version and provide error message. Bash is used here for sure.

Comment: I find that on Bash 4.1.2 I can get this to work, but only if I split over two lines, breaking after the function name.

Comment: The code-snippet me used in the time of rising this Q is unfortunately not in version control. For production I needed to replace it with working form, see previous comments here. My later trial to provide here info reg. resulting error messsage did not lead to reproducibility.